# Объясните как работает функция генератор

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я проходил курс и во время изучения генераторов и `yield` встретил такой код с непонятным объяснением. Не могли бы вы построчно написать комментарии к функции и сделать общее объяснение

```py
def find_word(file, word):
    g_indx = 0
    for line in file:
        indx = 0
        while (indx != -1):
            indx = line.find(word, indx)
            if indx > -1:
                yield g_indx + indx 
                indx += 1

        g_indx += len(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Генераторы это итерируемые объекты, но не сохраняющие значения в память, а генерирующие новое значение при попытке получить следующий элемент (По генератору можно пройти циклом только 1 раз и нет доступа к индексам) когда в функции появляется `yield` она, останавливает выполнение и передаёт объект в цикл.
К примеру при запуске этого кода:

```py
def find_word(file, word):
    g_indx = 0  # Индекс начала строки в файле
    for line in file:  # Идём по каждой линии
        indx = 0  # Индекс слова в строке
        while (indx != -1):  # Пока есть слово
            indx = line.find(word, indx)  # Находим следующие слово
            if indx > -1:  # Если слово было найдено
                print('Found!')  # Добавил для наглядности
                yield g_indx + indx  # Возвращаем индекс от начала файла
                # Прибавляем к строчному индексу 1
                # Чтобы это слово не находилось find
                indx += 1
        # Добавляем к индексу начала строки её длину
        g_indx += len(line)


for index in find_word("строка 1\n2. строка 2\nТретья строка".splitlines(), "строка"):
    print(index)
```

Результат будет следующим:

```
Found! # Функция выполняется пока не найдёт слово
0      # После передаёт в цикл
Found! # И когда тело цикла отработало продолжает свою работу
11
Found!
26
```

Следующее значение генератора также можно получить с помощью функции `next(iter)`